# tinymce bold content display as plain text

Tags: php, tinymce

When viewing data in HTML the content is shown as plain text without  tags. However italic is working fine.

In the database, content is shown below.

```
<p><strong>mmmmmmmm<em>mmmmmmmm</em></strong></p>
```

But when viewing it displays as,

> mmmmmmmm*mmmmmmmm*

I am using this as my js:

```
<script src='https://devpreview.tiny.cloud/demo/tinymce.min.js'></script>


   <script>
   tinymce.init({
    selector: '#textarea1',
    formats: {
        bold : {inline : 'b' },  
     },
    });
   </script>
```

I think the problem is with `<strong>` tag and it should be replaced with `<b>` tag. How can I replace strong with b tag?

Comment: *"How can I replace strong with b tag?"* ... seems a bit "back-to-front" as `<b>` carries no semantic weight; in the vast majority of cases you'd want to use `<strong>` over `<b>`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the question. I changed the code into the below one.

```
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#textarea1',
    formats: {
        bold : {inline : 'b' },
    },
    extended_valid_elements:'u,b',
    invalid_elements:'strong'
  });
  </script>
```